# Solidus: cannot find generator for rails g spree:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree, solidus

I'm having a problem using Rails with Solidus where `rails generate spree:install` is giving me an error in terminal that says `Could not find generator 'spree:install'. Maybe you meant 'devise:install', 'responders:install' or 'spree:dummy'`

I have rails 5.2.4.4, ruby 2.7.1, ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 and sqlite3 3.31.1 running on ubuntu 20.04 lts. I'm trying to install Solidus 2.10

I followed the documentation and added the solidus gem and solidus_auth_devise gem in my Gemfile and ran bundle before running the generator but I still have this problem. I also tried following the github solution (https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/issues/3752) for this, it still doesn't work. I put the whole error below in a bitbucket code snippet... I'd appreciate any help.

https://bitbucket.org/goldenBoySailsLow/workspace/snippets/5LGqez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [solidus readme](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus#installation-options) - currently the generator is called `solidus:install`, so use

```
bin/rails generate solidus:install
```

**upd**: verified with exact versions of rails and solidus on ruby 2.7.2, bug does not appear in `spree:install`.

Try stopping spring (spring stop) and cleaning bootsnap cache (`rm -rf tmp/cache/bootsnap-*`), looks like some stale code

Comment: That is for installing Solidus 2.11, I am trying to install Solidus 2.10

Comment: @C.Kraz updated, looks like spring/bootsnap is to blame, try restarting and cleaning the cache, the only thing different in my test was ruby 2.7.2 instead of 2.7.1

Comment: Actually this didn't work right away but it did after I upgraded my Ruby version to 2.7.2. Thank you.